# Scaling data to become withing a smaller range

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MATLAB: how to normalize/denormalize a vector to range [-1;1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684622/matlab-how-to-normalize-denormalize-a-vector-to-range-11)

I'm designing a Neural Network. As you know the inputs are preferred to be small, like between (0,1) or (-1,1). My data is in the range (1,9) .. how can I scale it to become within (-1,1) ?
I know I can use a Sin function, but I'm not sure if that's correct .. is there another way ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061276/how-to-normalize-a-vector-in-matlab-efficiently-any-related-built-in-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the minimum and maximum of your data, and then for each data point, subtract the minimum and divide by (max-min). This is called normalization-- all your inputs will be in the range 0-1